# How to set deflult BootstrapToggle to ON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/).
when i added Toggle button on page it set by default `OFF` even though i have set by default `checked` but still it shows me `OFF`.
How i can set it to `ON`? Here is my code :

```
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activate" data-off="Deactivate" th:field="${cen_group.status}" name="status"  data-th-size="normal" id="group_activation_status" data-th-style="slow">
```

Comment: I copied your code into one of my projects and the checkbox is on when I render the view.

Comment: have you set all the checkboxes to off somewhere in the code? :D

Comment: No , but i thing its setting by Thymleaf object `th:field="${cen_group.status}"` to `OFF`.

Comment: try to have a look if you are setting it to off in somewhere, because i tried and its working fine, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/zjjkq4m5/

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this, and it seems working for me successfully.

```html
<input class="form-control" type="checkbox" data-th-checked="true" th:checked="true" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Activate" data-off="Deactivate" th:field="${cen_group.status}" name="status"  data-th-size="normal" id="group_activation_status" data-th-style="slow">
```

**I just put these attributes:** `data-th-checked="true" th:checked="true"` and now my home page is showing by default `ON`.